# How to combine two as_json methods to one correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

In my Model I have a working as_json method as follows:

```
  def as_json(options = {})
    super(options.merge(include: [:user, comments: {include: :user}]))
  end
```

This method is for including users in comments.

Now I need to add almost the same thing in the same model for answers:

```
  def as_json(options = {})
    super(options.merge(include: [:user, answers: {include: :user}]))
  end
```

**How do I combine these two as_json methods, so that I have one as_json method?**

Don't laugh but I am struggling with this for 3 days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of the reasons why you should not use the built-in `to_json` to serialize ActiveRecord models.

Instead, you should delegate the task to another object called serializer. Using a serializer allows you to have **illimitate representations** (serializations) of the same object (useful if the object can have different variants such as with/without comments, etc) and **separation of concerns**.

Creating your own serializer is stupid simply, as simple as having

```
class ModelWithCommentsSerializer
  def initialize(object)
    @object = object
  end

  def as_json
    @object.as_json(include: [:user, comments: {include: :user}])) 
  end
end

class ModelWithAnswersSerializer
  def initialize(object)
    @object = object
  end

  def as_json
    @object.as_json(include: [:user, answers: {include: :user}])) 
  end
end
```

Of course, that's just an example. You can extract the feature to avoid duplications.

There are also gems such as [`ActiveModelSerializers`](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) that provides that feature, however I prefer to avoid them as they tend to provide a lot of more of what most of users really need.

Comment: Is this the correct way to call this serializer model in your example above? `ModelWithCommentsSerializer.new(my_users_instance)`

Comment: `ModelWithCommentsSerializer.new(my_users_instance).as_json` or it depends how you define your serializer.

Comment: ok, i am stuck at: "Creating your own serializer is stupid simply". where should this serializer class from your example be defined? If you could give me a link, that would be nice. I only find ActiveModelSerializers related stuff.

Comment: i am going with ActiveModelSerializers, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
def as_json(other_arg, options = {})
  as_json(options.merge(include: [:user, other_arg: {include: :user}])) 
end
```

And then you can call:

```
MyModel.as_json(:comments)
MyModel.as_json(:answers)
```

Comment: where do I call this?

Comment: you can call Model.as_json(:comments) or Model.as_json(:answers), but I think the solution from Rich Peck will be better

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to override core Rails functionality - not good practice unless absolutely necessary.

--

[This](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html) says the following:

> To include associations use :include:

```
user.as_json(include: :posts)
# => { "id" => 1, "name" => "Konata Izumi", "age" => 16,
#      "created_at" => "2006/08/01", "awesome" => true,
#      "posts" => [ { "id" => 1, "author_id" => 1, "title" => "Welcome to the weblog" },
#                   { "id" => 2, "author_id" => 1, "title" => "So I was thinking" } ] }
```

You could call:

```
@answers.as_json(include :users)
```

--

Ohhhhhhhh:

> Second level and higher order associations work as well:

```
user.as_json(include: { posts: {
                       include: { comments: {
                                      only: :body } },
                       only: :title } })
# => { "id" => 1, "name" => "Konata Izumi", "age" => 16,
#      "created_at" => "2006/08/01", "awesome" => true,
#      "posts" => [ { "comments" => [ { "body" => "1st post!" }, { "body" => "Second!" } ],
#                     "title" => "Welcome to the weblog" },
#                   { "comments" => [ { "body" => "Don't think too hard" } ],
#                     "title" => "So I was thinking" } ] }
```

So looks like you could call:

```
@answers.to_json(include: comments: { include: :users })
```